# Because of + Noun phrases

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Please consider the sentence below.

“The big record label system was going through a lot of upheaval because of the internet taking away all the sales and lots of people getting fired “

What do you call this  **“the internet taking away all the sales and lots of people getting fired** ”

Is it Noun phrases ?

Comment: What research have you done? What is your understanding of noun phrases? Do you recognize the form of the verbs "taking" and "getting"? Do you recognize the preposition before that phrase, and do you know what kinds of constituents can follow prepositions? Providing some details will help you to get a good answer.

Comment: As fas as I know, noun phrases is a group of words. However, what I understand is Because of + N but I am not sure if phrases can be followed after Because of? Since “the internet taking away all the sales and lots of people getting fired ” sound like a sentence for me (Just without helping Verb). That is why I need to know if that was a phrase, what kind of phrases is that?

Comment: It's a subordinate clause functioning as complement of the preposition "of".

Comment: Thank you BillJ. However, “the internet taking away all the sales and lots of people getting fired ” is not a sentence since it has no helping verb between “was taking” and “were getting” and the sentence must be followed after because not because of. In this case, can it be subordinate clause?